# gridview sum of column

Tags: c#, gridview, sum, devextreme, gridcontrol

I want to taking the sum of the numbers in the two columns and write to in textedit. the code does not give an error but it does not do the operating. Where's the problem?

```
void Numbersum()
    {
        int sumday = 0;
        int sumnight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

            sumday += Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Day").ToString());
            sumnight += Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Night").ToString());
        }
        textEdit26.Text = sumday.ToString();
        textEdit27.Text = sumnight.ToString();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j4qa.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question tags *devextreme* but it seems you are actually looking for *xtraGrid* in any case for [dxDataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/) you can use the [cellValue](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/#cellValuerowIndex_dataField) method.

```
grid.cellValue(rowIndex, dataField);
```